# How to find all entries with matching IDs between two objects in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm dealing with two objects formatted like this.

```
   {
        "MediaListCollection": {
            "lists": [
                {
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "mediaId": 121,
                            "score": 0
                        },
                        {
                            "mediaId": 5114,
                            "score": 10
                        }
    }
```

I want to make a new object with all of the entries that appear in both objects (using mediaID as a key). I tried this code but apparently it doesn't work in React because filter is only used on arrays, not objects:

```
const sameShows = user1Shows.filter(user1Shows.filter(shows1 => user2Shows.some(shows2 => user1Shows.mediaID === user2Shows.mediaID)))
```

Using `Object.entries(user1shows)` doesn't fix the problem. I get a `[object Array] is not a function` error.

Comment: `user1shows` is an object, but `user1shows.MediaCollection.lists` is an array

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Solutions don't belong in questions. If you like, post and accept an answer. Your solution is in the [edit log](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71040882/revisions) in case you need it.